# How to access at the local configuration on Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration, zend-framework2

I have some configuration on `local/config/xxx/config.ini` and a `local/config/xxx/config_base.ini`.

How can I access at there configuration on Zend Framework 2. I have an instance of the ServiceProvider but I cannot access at these config. It only ready the `module.config.php` (ex with `$config = $sm->get('Config');`)

I found that I can use this for read an ini file:

```
$config = (new Zend\Config\ReaderIni())->fromFile(getcwd() . '/local/config/xxx/config.ini');
```

But then how to merge the two configurations?

Comment: What is actually inside this config?

Answer (score 1):

Why would do you use `.ini` extension for your config files? As you can read in the [documentation on **Advanced Configuration Tricks**](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html) config files should be stored as `.php` files. They contain arrays holding the keys and values of your configuration and they will be automatically read from the autoload folders and merged with the module configuration files.

> Once configuration is aggregated from all modules, the ConfigListener will also merge application configuration globbed in specified directories (typically config/autoload/).

Here you can also find the folder pattern used to find the files it needs to merge:

> ```
> // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
> // modules are loaded. These effectively overide configuration 
> // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
> 'config_glob_paths' => array(
>    'config/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
> ),
> ```

The advantage is that you don't need a separate file reader and you can access your custom config from the service manager directly like you would do for other configs.

```
$config = $sm->get('Config');
$webhost = $config['my_param'];
```

Another advantage is that you can setup your production environment to cache the config files which will dramatically increase the performance of the bootstrapping procedure (reading files is a slow process).

I would suggest you rename your file extension to `.php` and follow the documentation for setting up your custom configuration values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it actually doesn't answer my question. I **have to** use an .ini file because the company that build the project using this type of configuration.

Comment: @Simoyw Then I still think it would be better to convert the `ini` file to a `php` file.

Answer (score 0):

When using the skeleton application, the system configuration is by default in `config/application.config.php`.

```
/ config.php
return array(
    'webhost'  => 'www.ekio.rw',
    'database' => array(
        'adapter' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'params'  => array(
            'host'     => 'db.ekio.rw',
            'username' => 'dbuser',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'dbname'   => 'mydatabase'
        )
    )
);
```

Then,

```
// Consumes the configuration array
$config = new Zend\Config\Config(include 'config.php');

// Display a configuration datum (results in 'www.ekio.rw')
echo $config->webhost;
```